# TextView looks different in Android app when uploading the Bundle instead of the APK

Tags: android, textview, styles, apk, bundle

I have a TextView in the main screen of an app, and everything went fine until I tried the new bundle feature and avoided uploading the apk file.

This particular TextView should look quite big and centered because of the style applied to the text, and when debugging through USB it does so, but when the app is on Google Play and uploaded via bundle instead of using an apk, the text looks small and placed to the left side of the screen.

The layout file is the following and you can see the TextView at first place inside the LinearLayout.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image_v"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/activity_main_title"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/title_text" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_test_global"
                style="@style/main_buttons_text"
                android:text="@string/b_activity_main_test_general"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_disabled"
                android:onClick="b_activity_main_test_general_onClick"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.032"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </View>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_test_temes"
                style="@style/main_buttons_text"
                android:text="@string/b_activity_main_test_temes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_disabled"
                android:onClick="b_activity_main_test_temes_onClick"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.032"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </View>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_failed_questions"
                style="@style/main_buttons_text"
                android:text="@string/failed_preguntes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_disabled"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.032"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </View>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_failed_questions_erase"
                style="@style/main_buttons_text"
                android:text="@string/failed_preguntes_erase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_disabled"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.032"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </View>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonProximsCursos"
                android:text="@string/buttonMainActivityProximsCursos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_disabled"
                android:onClick="buttonMainActivityProximsCursos_onClick"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                style="@style/buttonMainActivityProximsCursos_style" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.032"
                android:layout_height="0dp">
            </View>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/test_altres"
                style="@style/main_buttons_text"
                android:text="@string/b_activity_main_exit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/b_activity_main_exit"
                android:onClick="b_activity_main_exit_onClick"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </View>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:onClick="b_activity_main_logo_onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_fons_pantalla" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: apk and app bundle should have the same design, did you try the aab on a different device compare to the device you test using apk? and kindly post the xml layout of your concern problem

Comment: Sorry @L2_Paver I have now posted the xml layout, thanks for helping